# What is faster, a big joined query with more PHP or multiple small selects with less PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, database-performance

I'm running a cron task which makes lots of queries to a `MySQL` server. The big issue is that the server runs extremely slowly sometimes.

I've got a relatively big query with 4 tables left joined between them, and 4 smaller queries with `natural join`s that also attack the first table. After throwing those queries, I then process the results and group them using `PHP`.

What I'm planning is to somehow mix those 5 queries into just one big query, and then letting `PHP` do some quick `sort()`s when I need to do so.

I'm also told `MySQL` queries run faster than `PHP` in terms of filtering and sorting, but I'm reasonably worried about it when talking about having 7 or 8 left joins. Some more specs about these queries (which I can't copy because of company policies):

- Every fetched row and field will be visited at least once.
- Every query runs based on a single main table, with some "wing" tables.
- Every query uses the same `GROUP BY` rule.
- Currently the `PHP` code splits some secondary queries results into multiple arrays. It should, if using a big query, also sort the results by multiple parameters.

So, due to these problems, and maybe as a rule of thumb:

**What is faster, a big joined query with more PHP or multiple small selects with less PHP?**

Comment: As a general rule, the fewer 'round trips' to the server the better, with 'one' being optimal

Comment: It's rather difficult to answer this. The execution time of a script and the queries in it depends on many things. As Strawberry said, you should try to limit the number of access to your database, so the ultimate goal should be to have your one query that does everything optimized as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, my aim is of course go for one query if it is faster, but running a single query involves more PHP than before. In fact, let me rephrase the question to match the very big issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, the less queries the better. There is an overhead for passing a query to MySQL, however complex the query is. However php is surprisingly fast for some things, and if you are not using indexes for a sort (which sounds possible if you are effectively sorting the results of several queries unioned together) the performance of a sort in php might well be comparable or even better.

Where there is a big difference is where you get the results of one query and then perform another query for each returned row on the first query. It is quite easy in this situation for the number of queries to get out of hand rather rapidly without being noticed. At work I found a menu generation script that had one query to get the high level menu items and then another query for each high level item to get the child menu items. This was easily rewritten as a join, but the surprising part is the performance difference, with the time taken to generate the menu dropping from 0.2 seconds to 0.002 seconds.

But it is a case by case decision. I had a requirement to return some values based on a levenshtein calculated value (essentially a score of how different 2 strings are). Using a mysql custom function this was possible and greatly reduced the number of rows returned but was quite slow. The php levenshtein function is massively faster, and it proved to be more efficient to return several times as many rows and then process them in php to get the levenshtein value and then drop the no longer required records.

In the situation you describe I suspect the difference might be marginal. It would appear you will only be doing 4 queries rather than 1 more complex query. However without seeing the table structures and queries (which unfortunately you can't provide) it is difficult to be certain. It might well be efficient to do a single reasonable complex query but ignore the sorting where not strictly necessary, and then perform that in php (usort with a user defined comparison can be useful for this).

There is the further issue that a complex query is more difficult to maintain. While there are plenty of people who can nail a php script together or who can understand a simple SQL query, the number who can understand complex SQL queries is worryingly small.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am planning to roll **on small queries**, "as is", because I've run a quick test on how faster could be a couple of combined queries with sorting/filtering (some `WHERE`s couldn't be totally matched) and it showed up particularly slower than before, actually (by 50%, on a 1000 "benchmark run").

Answer (score 0):

From my experience SQL queries are faster. I also use many tables in some of my apps and found that that using simple queries and collecting sets of data in PHP is slower and the performance is really improved if you put everything on SQL side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, a big query also implies I should be doing heavier processes with PHP (starting by sorting, which I am not doing so at the time)

Comment: so sort in SQL as well - basically what I learned is that the performance is much improved if you put as much as you can on SQL side; I know that it's very easy to do everything in PHP instead of SQL especially if your not so confident in SQL, but I think you won't regret it

Comment: I'd like to do all the sorting with MySQL, but every query was sorting differently at first, so I can't find a MySQL-ish way to completely resort everything with a single query, if there is one way :(